# Default account team in apex code

Tags: apex

I was wondering how one would create a default account team in apex code. I'm trying to create a test class where it is being used but I cannot figure out how to add a default team.

Comment: Rachel -- You will get more help if you [edit] your post and add the code that isn't working/what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

The [Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) has the best documentation on standard objects, though even here the explanations aren't always clear.  It looks like you need to use the `UserAccountTeamMember` object for default account teams.